# SSRS: Report export to excel, excluding specific columns

Tags: excel, reporting-services

Is it possible with ssrs to export report to excel in such way that some of the columns will be removed? Columns should be visible in report, but when exporting to excel I would like to remove certain columns. There is possibility to hide certain columns with expression *(=IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.Name Like "EXCEL*", True, False))*, but when importing to excel there will be just empty column without data, but I do not need this column in excel at all. Just wondering is it somehow doable?

Comment: I 'think' its only possible with column groups. If you just try to set the visibility property all the textboxes within a column you're basically just making all the cells invisible but not the column itself. If you have a matrix with column groups you can set the visibility as you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

Create two versions of your matrix, using the same dataset; one for regular use and one for excel export (less columns). Create a parameter, name = "Excel", label = "Excel version?", with value/label options Yes/No.

Set expression in the visibility options of your matrices to correspond with the Yes/No options of that parameter.

Visibility option for regular matrix, select "show or hide based on an expression":

```
=Parameters!Excel.Value=No
```

Visibility option for excel matrix, select "show or hide based on an expression":

```
 =Parameters!Excel.Value=Yes
```

Comment: In this case I would advice hiding columns on the same matrix, instead of using two seperate matrices